# Buildozer error in building andorid apk inside virtual environment

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy, buildozer

Hi I wanted to build an android apk using my macbook pro. I'm doing it inside a virtual environement. I'm new to macbook pro and creating android using python and kivy. I used the sample program given in kivy documentation. To build the apk, I ran this command:

```
build android debug deploy
```

Now I get this error:
[image: error from building android apk using buildozer]

I already searched for problem, but I can't understand a thing:
1. https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/509
2. https://github.com/sjml/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh.d.symlink/functions/pip

Answer (score 0):

It's currently a limitation of buildozer, it can't be used in a virtualenv, if you don't want to pollute your operating system, you can use the --user flag instead, which will install buildozer in your user environment, and if you really want to isolate that, i guess you could create a new user just for that, and use sudo -u buildozer buildozer to run buildozer as the buildozer user (that you would have created), but unless you want to dive into buildozers code, and fix it for that, just don't try using it in a virtualenv.